# Why does differentiation of a tensor increase its rank?

Tags: derivatives, tensors, general-relativity, tensor-rank

There is a statement in both Wald and Carroll's GR texts that, in short, state that the derivative of a $(k,l)$-tensor is a $(k,l+1)$-tensor. In both places this as stated as though it should be obvious, but I am having trouble developing an intuition for this.

Could someone explain this? I am most comfortable thinking about tensors with the "slot machine" intuition, so if it could be explained in terms of "why the derivative increases the number of vector slots" that would be appreciated.

Comment: A scalar function is a (0,0)-tensor. The gradient of the said scalar function is a (0,1)-tensor (a vector).  So you have probably already used this concept for a long time.

Answer (score 3):

In short, these are directional derivatives, and the extra slot is for the vector that says what the direction is.

Comment: Ah great. Thank you. That makes sense.